# How to make a class template that wraps a function in a noexcept-detectable, callable object, to use as a std::unique_ptr custom deleter?

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr, parameterization, generic-lambda

Is it possible to use object type and free functions as parameters for creating custom deleters for `std::unique_ptr` ?

I'm new to templates and came up till here:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename FreeFunc> struct ObjectDeleter {
  const FreeFunc &free_func;
  ObjectDeleter(const FreeFunc &free_func) : free_func(free_func){
      
  }
  void operator()(T *item) 
  {
    if (item) {
      free_func(item);
    }
  }
};
struct Foo{};
void internal_foo_free(Foo *){}
struct Bar{};
void internal_bar_free(Bar *){}

using unique_foo_ptr = 
         std::unique_ptr<Foo, ObjectDeleter<Foo>([](Foo *foo){internal_foo_free(foo);});
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

error:

```
<source>:19:48: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
   19 |          std::unique_ptr<Foo, ObjectDeleter<Foo>([](Foo *foo){internal_foo_free(foo);});
      |                                                ^
<source>:3:48: note: provided for 'template<class T, class FreeFunc> struct ObjectDeleter'
    3 | template<typename T, typename FreeFunc> struct ObjectDeleter {
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:50: error: lambda-expression in template-argument only available with '-std=c++2a' or '-std=gnu++2a'
   19 |          std::unique_ptr<Foo, ObjectDeleter<Foo>([](Foo *foo){internal_foo_free(foo);});
      |                                                  ^
<source>:19:87: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   19 |          std::unique_ptr<Foo, ObjectDeleter<Foo>([](Foo *foo){internal_foo_free(foo);});
      |                                                                                       ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

I was suggested to use function pointer (and I extend it to std::function also):

but that adds the possibility of adding throwing statements via the function pointer (or std::function), which the compiler or static analysers won't be able to detect. Parameterising using lambda will make sure that the no-one can add throwing statements in the destructor of std::unique_ptr. This is what I mean by "noexcept-detectable, callable object"

I'm using C++17.

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should clearly describe the issue, such as a program that you expect to compile but does not.

Comment: `template<class T, class FreeFunc>`? That doesn't seem to have anything to do with `std::unique_ptr` though, that's a basic template topic

Comment: It seems that your non-member cleanup function should always have type `void (*)(T*)`... no template type parameter `typename FreeFunc` is needed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the suggestion, but that adds the possibility of adding throwing statements via the function pointer, which the compiler or static analysers won't be able to detect. Parameterising using lambda will make sure that the no-one can add throwing statements in the destructor of unique_ptr.

Comment: So, is your question "How do I make a class template that wraps a function in a noexcept callable object, to use as a `std::unique_ptr` custom deleter?"

Comment: @parktomatomi it seems so

Comment: @puio: I didn't say to eliminate the `ObjectDeleter` wrapper, which is where you are able to annotate `noexcept` (but you forgot to do so).  None of your existing code does anything to prevent exceptions.

Comment: @BenVoigt passing throwing statements via function pointer will go undetected by compiler/ static analyzers. Using lambda as parameter avoids that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining because lambdas can't be used as template arguments (before C++20 anyway). Otherwise, lambdas are *already* callable objects that will not throw unless the function body throws, no wrapper class needed. You just have to do this awkwardness:

```cpp
auto myDeleter = [&x](Foo* v) { internal_foo_free(v); };
std::unique_ptr<Foo, decltype(myDeleter)> guard { create_foo(), myDeleter };
```

Originally, I interpreted this question as "I want compilation to fail if someone uses a custom deleter not marked `noexcept`". I asked about it, which I think is why you edited your title to include that wording.

`noexcept` is a qualifier for optimization hint/documentation purposes. It is totally on the honor system. You can throw right inside them, and your source will still compile (though a static analyzer might complain). If you wanted to enforce that a custom deleter only calls `noexcept` functions, in C++17 you can use a static assertion with the `noexcept` operator, which returns false if an expression calls a non-noexcept function:

```cpp
template <auto F>
struct NoExceptDeleter{
    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T* arg) const noexcept {
        static_assert(noexcept(F(arg)), "deleter must be marked noexcept");
        F(arg);
    }
};

void good_delete(foo* v) noexcept { free(v); }
std::unique_ptr<foo, NoExceptDeleter<good_delete>> good_guard { make_foo() };

void bad_delete(foo* v) { throw 0; }
std::unique_ptr<foo, NoExceptDeleter<bad_delete>> bad_guard { make_foo() }; // compile-error
```

Because this takes a function pointer, in C++17 you can only use it with non-capturing lambdas decayed to a function pointer with the `+` operator:

```cpp
auto good_lambda = [](foo* v) noexcept { free(v); }
std::unique_ptr<foo, NoExceptDeleter<+good_lambda>> lambda_guard;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/vdEov3

If you needed to capture inside your lambda, you'd have to use a stateful deleter:

```cpp
template <typename F>
struct StatefulNoExceptDeleter {
    F f;
    StatefulNoExceptDeleter(F f) : f(f) { }

    template <typename T>
    void operator ()(T* arg) const noexcept {
        static_assert(noexcept(f(arg)), "deleter must be marked noexcept");
        f(arg);
    }
};

/* ... */

int baz;
auto deleter = [&](Foo* t) noexcept {
    std::cout << "labmda: " << baz << std::endl;
    delete t;
};
std::unique_ptr<Foo, StatefulNoExceptDeleter<decltype(deleter)>> guard { 
    new Foo, 
    StatefulNoExceptDeleter<decltype(deleter)>{ deleter }
};
```

Comment: "lambdas can't be used as template arguments" how does the following work ? https://godbolt.org/z/zcfaM7

Comment: You're passing the lambda as a function argument there, which has been fine since C++11. You can't pass it as a non-type template argument untill C++20. You also can't put a lambda in `decltype` and pass it as a type argument until C++20. https://godbolt.org/z/sE9aP3

Comment: okay, thanks! https://godbolt.org/z/cv9d3M It's crashing. you need to run the output in the demo link you gave.

Comment: Yikes, thanks for correct me! It was calling the default constructor of the function pointer type, which of course is just a null pointer. Fixed answer.